# Android Application for fetch and parse xml

Tags: android, xml

I have written code for Android Application for fetch and parse xml.but i am not able call method `getfeed()` from another class.

Code is given below

```
public class RssReader extends Activity {
    private RssFeed feed =null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        feed=new getFeed(Url);
    }
}
```

another class given below

```
private RssFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
{
    try
    {
        URL url= new URL(urlToRssFeed);
        SAXParserFactory factory =SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlreader=parser.getXMLReader();
        RssHandler theRSSHandler=new RssHandler();
        xmlreader.setContentHandler(theRSSHandler);
        InputSource is=new InputSource(url.openStream());
        xmlreader.parse(is);
        return theRSSHandler.getFeed();
    }
    catch (Exception ee)
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is another class ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If getFeed() is in your class RssFeed (make sure it's public), then instead of `feed=new getFeed(Url);`, use:

```
feed = new RssFeed();
feed.getFeed(Url);
```

You might want to check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android) regarding RSS Reading on Android.

Answer (score 0):

1. Is getFeed a Class?  If it is, does it extend/implement RssFeed?  If not, and it is a method, you should get rid of the `new` operator in front of getFeed, because that is not valid.
2. Where is `Url` defined?  I do not see it in the listed code...
3. Do you expect this `Activity` to do anything?  Depending on what `getFeed(Url)` does, your code does not appear to do anything (except maybe parse some xml, but it does nothing with the method output).  Perhaps you are just stuck on this first issue though...

Answer (score 0):

As the calling method and method defination both are in different class

```
private RssFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)
```

Here the access specifier is `private`. Private methods cannot be accessed outside the class. so change the access specifer into public.
write
`public RssFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)` instead of `private RssFeed getFeed(String urlToRssFeed)`

Thanks
Deepak